# I don't know how to understand the Wildcard type in Java

Tags: java, generics

I am reading the Core Java (9th edition) by Cay S. Horstmann and Gary Cornell. After making an effort, I cannot still understand the **? super Manager**. Here are some materials relating to this question.

```
public class Pair<T> {
    private T first;
    private T second;

    public Pair(T first, T second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public void setFirst(T first) {
        this.first = first;
    }

    public void setSecond(T second) {
        this.second = second;
    }

    public T getFrist() {
        return this.first;
    }

    public T getSecond() {
        return this.second;
    }
}
```

The **Manager** inherits from **Employee**, and **Executive** inherites from **Manager**. *Pair* has methods as follows:

```
void setFirst(? super Manager)
? super Manager getFirst()
```

Since *? super Manager* denotes any supertype of **Manager**, why I cannot call *setFirst* method with **Employee** (it is obvious that Employee is the supertype of Manager), but only with type **Manager** or a subtype such as **Executive**(but Executive is the subtype of Manager, not a supertype of Manager)?

Comment: [This question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847162/java-generics-super-keyword) might answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can read and re-iterate it over and over again - as it has been many times already. In a comment to your question, Philipp already [linked to a question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847162/java-generics-super-keyword) which tries to answer it. For me, [the explanation of Uncle Bob](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.BoundedWildcards) did the trick.

He writes (next to a lot of other good stuff):

> A `List<? super Shape>` is a list into which you may add Shapes. Another way to think of this is that the type `<? super T>` is an unknown type that `T` can substitute for. You may have to read that several times before you understand it. I certainly did. So here's yet another way to think about it. The type `<? super T>` is a type that `T` is derived from. It is a base class of `T`. Clearly if `D` is derived from `B` then you can put `D` instances into a `List<B>`. Likewise, since `T` derives from `<? super T>`, you can put `T` instances into a `List<? super T>`. Follow? No? Neither did I for awhile. It takes a bit of getting used to.

What this means in the end is that your assumption you'd be able to put super-types of `Manager` into your `List<? super Manager>` is wrong. That's not what is meant here. The `super` keyword solves the problem of not being able to *insert* stuff into generic places while you were able to get some out (with `extends`).

Imagine two pairs, one that extends Manager, one that "supers" it:

```
Pair<? extends Manager> subPair = new Pair<Manager>();
Pair<? super Manager> superPair = new Pair<Manager>();
```

What you can **never** do, is insert an `Employee` in any of these:

```
subPair.setFirst(new Employee());
superPair.setFirst(new Employee());
```

If you want managers, employees will never be enough. And it's worse: you can't even insert an `Executive` into your `subPair`, even though `Executive extends Manager`. It won't compile either:

```
subPair.setFirst(new Executive());
```

**Edit:**
Why is that? Well, your generic `subPair` always refers to some "explicit" `Pair`, `Pair<Manager>` in this case. It just as well might have referred to a `Pair<CoManager>` (with `CoManager extends Manager`). Java won't know the explicit type that's actually used and thus can't allow you insertions.

But `super` comes to the rescue. With `super` you can insert Managers and their sub-types into your `Pair`. And that is what `super` is for: Inserting.

```
superPair.setFirst(new Executive());
```

**Edit:** Any why does that work? While `extends` guarantees you *some* type that implements (or derives from) `Manager`, `super` guarantees you *any* such type. So, while with `extends` you get a *specific type* with (at least) the `Manager` interface, with `super` you can insert *any type* with the `Manager` interface.

And for the bigger picture, I really suggest reading the article of Uncle Bob.

Comment: "you can't even insert an Executive into your subPair, even though Executive extends Manager." Why not?

Comment: @Brandon With `extends` the compiler guarantees that `subPair` will be a `Pair` with some kind of objects deriving from `Manager`. It could very well be a `Pair` of `CoManager` and you cannot insert an `Executive` into a `Pair<CoManager>`. `super` on the other hand guarantees that `superPair` always is a `Pair` with elements that at least implement `Manager`. You can thus insert any kind of `Manager`. Admittedly, Java is a bit weird with this...

Comment: What is the difference between deriving from `Manager` and implementing `Manager`?  In an OOP world, those feel like synonyms to me.  I have been programming in Java professionally for 6 years now and still do not understand the difference between `super` and `extends`.

Comment: @Brandon I just edited my answer. You're right, deriving from something and implementing it, in an OOP world, basically is the same, at least for the purpose here. The trick lies more between *some* and *any*. I hope my addition helps.

Answer (score 0):

The difference seems to be the purpose of your variable.

If you use a variable of type `Pair` to read then you use `Pair<? extends Manager>`
In this case, when calling a method of pair that returns something parameterized, you will have the benefit of type-safe. But you almost cannot write anything into it, always a compilation error.

On the other hand, if you use a variable of type `Pair` to write then you use
`Pair<? super Manager>`. In this case, when calling a method of `Pair<>` type that receives a parametrized variable of type (or subtype) of `Manager`, you have the type safe.

Honestly, I don't see the difference between `Pair<? super Manager>` and  `Pair<Manager>` except that when you use `Pair<? super Manager>`
 the read methods in Pair<> returns generic java Object (ie not type safe for read, the compiler kind of discourages reading in this case)

I think seeing it as read and write like this is easier.

Now back to the why you cannot write an `Employee` object into your `Pair<? super Manager>`. This is because `<? super Manager>`
is actually a type that extends some unknown supertype of `Manager`. And because it is unknown, you don't know if `Employee` actually is a subtype of that unknown type.

Even more concrete: let's say `Manager` also implements an interface `IManager`.
Then `<? super Manager>` can be an `IManager` object and now `Employee` is not a valid substitution of `IManager` (because it is not a subtype of `IManager`). In this case, any subtype of `Manager` can be a substitution because it will be subtype of any unknown supertype of `Manager`. You can call `setFirst(Executive e)` here.